# Prove that if $A_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $B_n \rightarrow \infty$ then (a) $A_n+B_n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, proof-writing, infinity

Let $A > 0$ be given. There exists a natural number $N_1$  Such that $a_n > A$ for all $n > N_1$.

Let $A > 0$ be given. There exists a natural number $N_2$ Such that $b_n > A 
 $for all $n >N_2$.

Now let $N = \max\{N_1,N_2\}$. For all $n > N$, $a_n$ + $b_n > 2A$ by previous steps $> A$ as required.

My question is would it have been better to let $A = \frac{A}{2}$ as I would deduce that the sequence $> A$ straight away. Basically, am I wrong for doing what I did ?

Comment: Both look fine to me.

Comment: Nice to see you learn some important stuff outside racing :)

Comment: Looks good — just needed to show the sum exceeds any finite value

Comment: @User5678 Sorry, I don’t understand

Comment: @JustWandering I may be returning to F1 next season with Haas to replace Mick so I’m trying to learn as much as possible : )

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Of course! We need more entertainment now that Latifi is gone :)

Comment: @NikitaMazepin Sorry — just meant you proved what you needed to :)

Comment: @User5678 Okay thank you!

Comment: From the statement is not clear if both sequences coverages to the *same* infinity.
If $A_n = n$ and $B_n = -n$ than $A_n + B_n \to 0$